# Modern MLM Software with Brains?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, amavis

So, right now we have a Postfix + Dovecot + Amavis server for our mail.

We do "group lists" as a gaint Alias.

The complaint has come up, that when someone sends an email to everyone@thecompany.com, that they then recieve a copy of the email themselves.

The only MLM i'm familiar with is EzMLM which i'm not aware of the above functionality, as well as I kinda dread getting it to work properly with postfix.

anyone have any suggestions on software that does the above?

Comment: Isn't user education a possible solution?  If anything, I'd think that seeing a copy of the message that looks the same as everyone else in the company got would be a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Mailman](http://www.list.org/) has the "not metoo" and "no dupes" user config options, which do exactly what you're looking for.

Additionally, Mailman is very easy to get working with postfix.